# Translation Golf XXXIX - I'm blue

Tags: traducción, translation-golf

> Game over! Winner: [blonfu with 20 chars](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/25956/13628).

---

Welcome to a new edition of the game! If this is your first time, there's some info for beginners at the end of this post.

---

Long-time players know I've got a thing for music. Here's [a song that you might've heard once or twice](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FlMHdhf0nvE):

> I have a blue house with a blue window
>   Blue is the color of all that I wear
>   Blue are the streets and all the trees are too
>   I have a girlfriend and she is so blue
>   Blue are the people here that walk around
>   Blue like my Corvette, it's in and outside
>   Blue are the words I say and what I think
>   Blue are the feelings that live inside me
>
> I'm blue da ba dee da ba daa
>   Da ba dee da ba daa, da ba dee da ba daa, da ba dee da ba daa
>   Da ba dee da ba daa, da ba dee da ba daa, da ba dee da ba daa
>
> <sub>(362 characters)</sub>

Yes, it is *Blue (Da Ba Dee)* by Eiffel 65.
There are differing opinions about the meaning of this song. Some would say that it tells us about a funny world where everything is colored blue, whereas others argue that it is a song about depression and 'blue' refers to feeling down. Answers can be based on any of those interpretations (or a mix of both) as long as they are coherent.

---

The goal is to translate the given text to Spanish, using as few letters as possible, while keeping all the original text's meaning and concepts more or less intact.

My own, non-golfed translation:

> Yo tengo una casa azul con una ventana azul. Azul es el color de todo lo que llevo puesto. Azules son las calles y todos los árboles son azules también. Tengo una novia y es super azul. Azul es la gente que camina por aquí alrededor, azul como mi Corvette lo es por dentro y por fuera. Azules son las palabras que digo y lo que pienso. Azules son los sentimientos que viven dentro de mí.
>  Soy azul, da bu di da bu dai, da bu di da bu dai, da bu di da bu dai, da bu di da bu dai, da bu di da bu dai, da bu di da bu dai, da bu di da bu dai.
>
>  <sub>(402 characters)</sub>

**Note**: "rhyme rules" do not apply to this edition.

- Rules: [Translation-golf rules](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2592/5481)
- Letter counter: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ermv0rh/2/embedded/result/)

You may want to check past [translation-golf](/questions/tagged/translation-golf) questions to get a feel of the game dynamics and the kind of answers expected.

Want to share translation ideas, ask for clarifications or just tease other contesters? Join us in [La Tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46061/la-), Spanish.SE's official chat room!

Have fun!

Comment: Tengo que hacer un replanteamiento completo - borro mi respuesta mientras elaboro una de nuevas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### 20 caracteres

> Veo todo azul: depresión

El tipo dice que las cosas son azules, no importa mucho qué cosas sean ya que podemos interpretarlo como una metáfora de la tristeza que siente así que ve todo lo que le rodea con un tinte azul.

Comment: @yotanka me la he jugado, viendo vuestras traducciones no había otra forma de superarlo, a ver que dice walen

Comment: entonces "Soy azul como todo lo demás" xD

Comment: Me sumo a los comentarios ya realizados. El texto original dice que hay una serie de cosas que, a juicio del cantante, son "azules/tristes". No se puede inferir que "todo es azul" pues. Considero que debe aparecer representada esa lista parcial de elementos azules en la respuesta, y coincido con @walen en que debería aparecer la figura del narrador.

Comment: @blonfu, en mi caso ¿Qué pasó con el toque final? ¿el *da ba dee da ba daa* o su adaptación al español?

Answer (score 4):

#### 31 caracteres

> [Ay](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4bUlvCX) de
>   mis cosas,
>   las [rúes](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WngeeRa),
>   la gente
>   y de mí.

Explicaciones:

- Cuando se usa *ay* seguido de la preposición *de* "denota pena, temor, conmiseración o amenaza". Se entiende que en este caso es pena.
- En "mis cosas" meto la casa (con sus ventanas), la ropa y el coche.
- En "las rúes" (calles) meto también a los árboles que adornan las calles.
- En "la gente" meto también a la novia, que es gente.
- En "mí" incluyo todo lo referente al que canta, incluyendo sus palabras y los sentimientos.

Answer (score 4):

#### 212 caracteres

> Mi casa, su ventana y mi ropa es azul. Las calles, los árboles mi
> novia, Mi Corvette, lo que pienso y digo y mi sentimientos tambien lo
> son.
>
> Soy azul da ba dee da ba daa Da ba dee da ba daa, da ba dee da ba daa,
> da ba dee da ba daa Da ba dee da ba daa, da ba dee da ba daa, da ba
> dee da ba daa

Answer (score 3):

### 61 char

> ¿Azul? Mi lar, ventana, vestir, amor, auto, mi ser, flora y calle
>   dabadí dabadá (bis)

lar por house, auto por Corvette, Mi ser por the words I say and what I think (...) the feelings that live inside me (...) I'm blue (mi ser incluye mis pensamientos, sentimientos, hablar y a mi, so pena de entrar en debates ontológicos), amor por girlfriend, calle por people y street (acepciones 1 y 6 DLE), y bis para la repetición del dabadí dabadá

Cualquier duda o cambio a pedir, comentar por favor

Answer (score 0):

**28 caracteres**

> Yo, lo mio y mi entorno somos azules.

Comment: Mismo comentario que a blonfu: el autor cita una serie de elementos que son azules, pero no se puede inferir de ahí que todo el entorno del cantante lo sea. Ejemplo: en la canción no se mencionan los animales: ¿son azules? ¿Son parte de su entorno? Creo que la lista se debería expandir un poco y no hacerla tan genérica.